# how to install update by CVE number

Tags: updates, security

In Redhat and Suse i can run below command in order to install a specific CVE.

for example:

```
yum update --cve CVE-2015-7547

zypper patch --cve=CVE-2015-7547
```

in this also possible in Ubuntu?

How can i install a specific CVE by its number?

Comment: closest package - https://packages.debian.org/jessie/debsecan

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` does not support this (nor does any frontend of `dpkg` that I know of, including `aptitude` and Synaptic). You an use the CVE tracker: https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/ to find out the matching package, but there's no automatic way.